# Pillow (PIL Fork): Error when using ImageFont/ImageDraw methods with custom font

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

After reading through much of the Pillow documentation, stack overflow, and the web, I have been unable to decipher this error message that is throwing off my application. My current setup:

- Python 3.7.6
- Pillow 7.0.0 [[Docs]](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html)

Below is a verifiable example of what I have been working on. Essentially, my error happens when I use `title_font` in place of where I use `default_font`. Emphasized by the 2 comments stating: `# TODO Aborts with error unless using default_font TODO`.

```
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image

def app():
    # Default Font with static size and font type
    default_font = ImageFont.load_default()

    # TODO Title Font that is the desired use
    title_font = ImageFont.truetype(font="~/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf", size=36)

    # Background Image to draw text on
    bg_img = Image.new(mode = "RGBA",size = (3480,2160), color="Green")

    # Creates an object that can be used to draw in the given image.
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(bg_img)

    txt = "Hello World"

    # TODO: Aborts with error unless using default_font TODO
    # Returns (width, height) of text in pixels with designated font
    txt_width, txt_height = default_font.getsize(txt)

    print(f"Text Width:{txt_width} Text Height: {txt_height}")

    # TODO: Aborts with error unless using default_font TODO
    # Draws "Hello World" onto background image
    d.text((10,60), text=txt, font=default_font, fill=(255,255,255,255))

    # Pop Up window
    bg_img.show()
```

Below is the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKifB.png) that I get back from both ImageDraw/ImageFont methods:

```
>>> app()
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _hb_language_get_default
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libraqm.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _hb_language_get_default
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libraqm.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have already tried:

- To change the path used for the custom font and to change to another font loading method (i.e. [ImageFont.load(filename)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#functions), [ImageFont.load_path(filename)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html#functions).
- To settle with `ImageFont.load_default()` but as you might be able to tell by running it, the default font is very small and there is no way of changing its size or style.

One last thing that I was not sure about was this line in the installation guide that recommended after `brew install` of the packages Pillow depends on:
 *Then see depends/install_raqm_cmake.sh to install libraqm.*
Can be found [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-on-macos) halfway through the **[Building on macOS](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-on-macos)** section. I have a nagging feeling this could be the cause but I simply do not understand what action it wants me to take.

Long time lurker, first time poster. Thank you for any help now and all the help afforded to me over the years!

**UPDATE: Used my example on another MacBook and it works fine. I am going to reset the one it wasn't working on and build from scratch. Thanks for all your assistance!**

Comment: Unfortunately, can't reproduce on Windows Prof. 10, PyCharm Prof. 2019.3, Python 3.8.1, Pillow 7.0.0, absolute path set to `verdana.tff`.

Comment: @Anomali007 tested on Linux, code is working fine

Comment: It's maybe related to your using tilde (`~`) as a shortcut for your HOME directory as that is a `bash`-ism. I would try  `ImageFont.truetype(font="/Users/ANOMALI007/Library/Fonts/Verdana.ttf" ...)`

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I attempted updating the absolute path of the font file to no avail.
@ZarakiKenpachi When installing Pillow did you do anything with _`depends/install_raqm.sh` to install libraqm_ ?

Comment: @Anomali007 nope. Pillow 7.0 installed from Pycharm with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used (like me) a Mac with OS Catalina or similar, and might have installed the mentioned library with "$ brew install libraqm" too.

I resolved it by changing the layout_engine, and due to this, not using 'libraqm' for PIL layout work in the background.

```
font = ImageFont.truetype(
            "/System/Library/Fonts/Keyboard.ttf", layout_engine=ImageFont.LAYOUT_BASIC, encoding=self.encoding, self.font_size,)
```

If you do this you might not be able to use Chinese or similar Fonts. I am not sure where, in 'brew', 'pyenv' or 'libraqm' is the issue but I try to find it out.